# Not able to plot diagram from Elasticsearch Lucene query in Grafana 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I am using Grafana with Elasticsearchas data source.
On each of my documents, I have a field "id" and "lastmodifiedDate".
I would like to show the table with the count of id's accordingly last modified date.

here is my document:

```
{
        "_index": "global_search",
        "_type": "News_Item",
        "_id": "48",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "48",
          "dueDate": 1478802600000,
          "lastModifiedDate": 1478802600000,
          "whenCreatedDate": 1477506600000,
          "ownerEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
          "owner": {
            "firstname": "ABC",
            "lastname": "Kumar",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
          },
          "subject": "USA','According to NBCDFW.com, an explosion at a silicon plant ",
          "status": "NEW",
          "updatedby": "ABC Kumar",
          "content": "Text data"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "global_search",
        "_type": "News_Item",
        "_id": "26",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "id": "26",
          "dueDate": 1477679400000,
          "lastModifiedDate": 1477679400000,
          "whenCreatedDate": 1477506600000,
          "researchTitle": "Flash Floods Hit Parts of Southern France",
          "ownerEmail": "xyz@gmail.com",
          "owner": {
            "firstname": "XYZ",
            "lastname": "Kumar",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
          },
          "subject": "Flash Floods Hit Parts of Southern France",
          "status": "MONITORING",
          "updatedby": "XYZ",
          "content": "Text2 data"
        }
      }
```

Question: How to plot table with count of id's according date?What is the exact Lucene query to plot the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with below query parameters:

```
Metric:
  Count
Group by:
  type: Date Histogram
  field: lastModifiedDate
```

Query field can be left blank.